# How do I make a splash screen end animation and start next activity?

Tags: android

I'm developing a mobile application in Android.
I have an initial animation; after that, control should transfer to the next activity.  The transfer doesn't happen.
Where did I go wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        StartAnimations();



    }

    private void StartAnimations() {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
        anim.reset();
        LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
        l.clearAnimation();
        l.startAnimation(anim);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
        iv.clearAnimation();
        iv.startAnimation(anim);

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
```

use Intent for your requirement

... slide_out_up.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="-100%" />

<alpha
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:toAlpha="0" />

 </set>
```

slide_in_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />

<alpha
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:toAlpha="1" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks
Please advise the next activity after the end of the animation to go.

alpha.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <alpha
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="3000" />
```

translate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="200%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="2000"
        android:zAdjustment="top" />
</set
```

Mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        StartAnimations();


    }

    private void StartAnimations() {

        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);

        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
        l.startAnimation(anim);

        Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        iv.startAnimation(anim2);

        anim2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                l.clearAnimation();
                iv.clearAnimation();

                //open your second activity

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
                startActivity(in);

            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you.
I apply the changes you mentioned.
But I was met with an error !!!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        StartAnimations();


    }

    private void StartAnimations() {

        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);

        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
        l.startAnimation(anim);

        Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        iv.startAnimation(anim2);

        anim2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                l.clearAnimation();
                iv.clearAnimation();

                //open your second activity

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }

    });
    }
```

Eror:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Error:(72, 6) error: reached end of file while parsing
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

Comment: are you hitting any API on Splash screen?

Comment: api:
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

Comment: can you please post me code of your alpha.xml, translate.xml and the code you are writing into onAnimationEnd()?